# Hash to custom array implementation

Tags: ruby, arrays

Last newbie question for today. There is a hash:

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

How to implement convert_to_arr(h) method with such output:

```
convert_to_arr(h) 
# ["Key: 'a', Value: '1'",  
# "Key: 'b', Value: '2'",  
# "Key: 'c', Value: '3'"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.map { |key, value| "Key: '#{key}', Value: '#{value}'" }

=> ["Key: 'a', Value: '1'", "Key: 'b', Value: '2'", "Key: 'c', Value: '3'"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
h.map{|k,v| "key: '#{k}' ,val: '#{v}'"}
# => ["key: 'a' ,val: '1'", "key: 'b' ,val: '2'", "key: 'c' ,val: '3'"]
```

Comment: Priti, thanks for all prompt and correct answers and good night! (in my country is 00:31, 21-07-2013)

Answer (score -1):

You could always implement a struct:

```
struct keyItem
{
    char key[30];
    int value;
}
```

And then do something like this:

```
keyItem h[3] =
{
    { "a", 1 },
    { "b", 2 },
    { "c", 3 }
}
```

Your function like this:

```
void print_keys(keyItem[] k, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Key: \"%s\", Value: '%d'\n", k[i].key, k[i].value);
    }
}
```